# Eliminar objeto de un array por medio de una función sigue apareciendo

Tags: php

Estoy bloqueado con la eliminación de un objeto dentro de un array. He creado una clase con un par de instancias que, posteriormente, he colocado en un array (`$arreglo`). Quiero conseguir que la función `eliminar()` borre por completo uno de esos objetos a partir de de la propiedad `id`. Lo he intentado por medio de `unset()` pero por lo que he leído, si está dentro de una función, el borrado solo es local. He estado buscando y no encuentro ninguna solución.

Entonces, ¿no hay ninguna para eliminar el objeto directamente dentro del foreach?

```
<?php

class Producto {
    public $id;
    public $nombre;
    public $descripcion;
    public $cantidad_stock;
    public $precio;

    public function __construct($id, $nombre, $descripcion, $cantidad_stock, $precio) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
        $this->cantidad_stock = $cantidad_stock;
        $this->precio = $precio;
    }

    public function get_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function set_id($x) {
        $this->id = $x;
    }

    public function get_nombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function set_nombre($x) {
        $this->nombre = $x;
    }

    public function get_descripcion() {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }

    public function set_descripcion($x) {
        $this->descripcion = $x;
    }

    public function get_cantidad_stock() {
        return $this->cantidad_stock;
    }

    public function set_cantidad_stock($x) {
        $this->cantidad_stock = $x;
    }

    public function get_precio() {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    public function set_precio($x) {
        $this->precio = $x;
    }

}

$arreglo = [new Producto(1, "avellanas", "frutos secos", 25, 15.12), new Producto(2, "bacalao", "pescado", 12, 25)];

?>    

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
    <input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="descripcion">
    <input type="text" name="stock" placeholder="cantidad en stock">
    <input type="text" name="precio" placeholder="precio">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $stock = intval($_POST['stock']);
    $precio = floatval($_POST['precio']);

    array_push($arreglo, new Producto($id, $nombre, $descripcion, $stock, $precio));
}

function mostrar($x) {
    foreach($x as $y) {
        $data = "Id: $y->id\nNombre: $y->nombre\nDescripción: $y->descripcion\nQuedan en Stock: $y->cantidad_stock\nPrecio: $y->precio\n<br>";
        echo $data;
    }
}

function datos($x,$y) {
    foreach($y as $obj) {
        if($obj->id == $x) {
            echo "Id: $obj->id\nNombre: $obj->nombre\nDescripción: $obj->descripcion\nQuedan en Stock: $obj->cantidad_stock\nPrecio: $obj->precio\n<br>";
        }
    }
}

function setting($id, $name, $desc, $price, $caja) {
    foreach($caja as $obj) {
        if($id == $obj->id){
            $obj->set_nombre($name);
            $obj->set_descripcion($desc);
            $obj->set_precio($price);
        }
    }
}

function eliminar($id, $caja) {
    foreach($caja as $obj){
        if($id == $obj->id){
            unset($obj);
        }
    }
}

eliminar(2, $arreglo);

datos(2, $arreglo);
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar referencias https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php por ejemplo `function eliminar($id, &$caja){...}` observe el `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el paso por referencia y eliminar del array desde la función una clave del array, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$arreglo = [
    (object) ['id'=>1, 'nombre'=>"avellanas", 'descripcion'=>"frutos secos", 'cantidad_stock '=>25, 'precio'=>15.12],
    (object) ['id'=>2, 'nombre'=>"bacalao", 'descripcion'=>"pescado", 'cantidad_stock '=>12, 'precio'=>25]
];


function eliminar($id, &$caja){
    // Recuperamos las claves junto al valor
    foreach($caja as $key => $obj){
        // Comparamos los id's
        if($id == $obj->id){
            // Si son iguales lo eliminamos
            unset($caja[$key]);
            // Rompemos el bucle para que no continue
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// eliminamos el id 1
eliminar(1, $arreglo);

var_dump($arreglo);

/* RESULTADO
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(7) "bacalao"
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(7) "pescado"
    ["cantidad_stock "]=>
    int(12)
    ["precio"]=>
    int(25)
  }
}
*/
```

Documentación: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!
Acabas de hacerme descubrir un mundo

:D

Comment: Perdona @Xerif, lo que no me queda claro es qué significa esto: $key => $obj
Y también el return, qué es lo que retorna?

Gracias

Comment: Ya tengo la sintaxis clave => valor (https://www.anerbarrena.com/php-foreach-4298/)
Pero sigo sin comprender lo que es el return vacío
:D

Comment: Se trata de una manera "especial" de tratar un `foreach()` en **PHP** en el que desglosas la clave y el valor. En tu caso, como iteras un `array` de objetos `$key` hace referencia a la posición del objeto dentro del `array` (su índice) y `$obj` hace referencia a los objetos. El `return` vacio simplemente es para cumplir el convenio de que una función siempre debe tener su `return`.

Comment: Genial!
Muchas gracias por la información

:D

Answer (score 2):

Como bien te han dicho, podrías pasar por referencia el `array` a la función `eliminar()`, para que las modificaciones que este sufra dentro de la función se vean reflejadas fuera de este.

Otra opción sería devolver el `array` actualizado y machacar el que tenías antes de llamar a la función.

```
function eliminar($id, $caja) {
    foreach($caja as $clave => $objeto){
        if($id === $objeto->id){
            unset($caja[$clave]);
        }
    }

    return $caja;
}

$arreglo = eliminar(2, $arreglo);

datos(2, $arreglo);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy útil y bien explicado

:D

Answer (score 2):

Como bien has leído, si usas [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) dentro de una función, lo que harás será modificar la instancia local de la variable (a no ser que uses [$GLOBALS](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.globals.php)). Para hacer lo que deseas, debes o [declarar que la variable de la función va a ser tratada como referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php) como te recomendó el compañero @Xerif, o modificar la versión global de la variable, o retornar una nueva variable en tu función que remplace a la global. como te recomendó el compañero @phpMyGuel.

Una posible solución, entre las muchas que existen, es que en vez de usar `unset`, uses [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php) para remover un índice específico del array si el objeto en ese índice contiene el `id` que deseas eliminar:

**Declarar la variable de la función como una variable pasada por referencia:**

```
function eliminar (&$caja, $id) {
    foreach($caja as $index => $obj) {
        if ($id == $obj['id']) {
            array_splice($caja, $index, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

eliminar($caja, 3);

var_dump($caja);
```

[Snippet en Ideone](https://ideone.com/a4OIGN)

**Modificando la variable global dentro de tu función:**

```
function eliminar ($id) {
    global $caja;       
    foreach($caja as $index => $obj) {
        if ($id == $obj[id]) {
            array_splice($caja, $index, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

eliminar(3);
```

[Snippet en Ideone](https://ideone.com/rsz3BV)

**Devolviendo una nueva variable para remplazar a la global:**

```
function eliminar ($caja, $id) {
    foreach($caja as $index => $obj) {
        if ($id == $obj[id]) {
            array_splice($caja, $index, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $caja;
}

$caja = eliminar($caja, 3);
```

[Snippet en Ideone](https://ideone.com/tckWf5)

Comment: Gracias!
Perfectamente explicado

:D

Comment: Solo como nota, si no se requiere la reordenacion de los índices la reconmendacion para eliminar es utilizar unset. Hay que tener en cuenta que unset es una construcción del lenguaje y será mas eficiente que cualquier función:  `unsed -> eliminar` mientras que `array_splice -> quitar, añadir, reordenar, retornar`

Comment: Cierto @Xerif, buena observación ;)